# Django Rest might not found api endpoint with slug

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have ViewSets with using `action` decorator.
All actions with slug work.
But there is one action which return `Page not found`

```
class DefectImageViewSet(GenericViewSet):
    queryset = DefectImage.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DefectImageListSerializer

    @action(
        methods=['get'],
        detail=False,
        url_path='<uuid:defect_id>', # This method not work in current case, 
                                      # but I using this definition method of slug everywhere
                                      # and it work
        # url_path=r'(?P<defect_id>[^/.]+)', # This is work in current case
        url_name='image-list'
    )
    def get_list(self, request, defect_id):
        queryset: QuerySet = self.get_queryset()
        queryset = queryset.filter(defect_id=defect_id)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

I tried to remove slug and set default value and all work, but as soon as I add a slug, it returns `Page not found`